# Pubnub async subscription causes thin server to quit

Tags: sinatra, thin, pubnub

I am trying to make a pubnub async subscription from a Sinatra application. I initialize the pubnub object from the app class and invoke the subscription like the following:

```
    pubnub.subscribe(
        :channel => 'channel_name',
        :http_sync => false,
        :callback => lambda do |message|
          ## Message Received!!!
          puts(message) ## print message
          return true
        end
    )
```

The above method is supposed to be non-blocking and return control to the main thread. But it is causing the Thin server to quit without throwing any error trace.

Comment: Please shoot us an email at support@pubnub.com and we'd be happy to assist.

Comment: Did you contact support and was your issue resolved?

Comment: Yes, it was resolved